# In Kotlin creating a parquet file with AvroParquetWriter only first record has value

Tags: kotlin, parquet, avro

I'm trying to write several records to a parqeut file using the following writer:

```
private fun createAvroWriter(schema: Schema, outputFile: HadoopOutputFile): ParquetWriter<GenericRecord>? {
        return AvroParquetWriter.builder<GenericRecord>(outputFile)
            .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
            .withSchema(schema)
            .withConf(Configuration())
            .withPageSize(500 * 1024)
            .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE)
            .build()
    }
```

I've created a list of records that adhere to a schema and now want to write them to a parquet file. If I use a loop over the list and write each record only the first record is written properly. By that I mean only the first record has values and after that each entry (of correct count) is filled with `null`. Is there something I should bear in mind while writing records to a parquet file?

I have tried iterating over the loop and writing each record and then closing the writer.

I expect each record written to have the values that are in the object.